How to simplify this finite binomial sum of Bessel functions?
Problem
My main problem is solving the following Fourier integral where $k \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
    I_1 &= \int^1_{-1}\text{d}x \frac{x^{2n+1} e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},\\
    I_2 &= \int^1_{-1}\text{d}x \frac{x^{2n} e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align}
I found solution at the bottom of this question, but I am struggling with simplifying it. Any help is appreciated!
My attempt
Because of the square root in the denominator, I thought about a solution in terms of Bessel functions. So I used the expansion of $x^n$ in terms of Chebyshev polynomials of the form
\begin{align}
    x^n = \frac{\alpha_0}{2} + \sum^\infty_{j = 1} \alpha_j T_j(x).
\end{align}
where for $j = 0, \dots,n$
\begin{align}
    \alpha_j = \begin{cases} 2^{-2n}
        \begin{pmatrix}
           2n+1 \\
           \frac{2n+1-j}{2} 
         \end{pmatrix} & 2n+1-j\:\text{even}\\
          0 & \text{else}
          \end{cases}
\end{align}
Distinguishing odd and even $n$ and the known identity
\begin{align}
    \pi J_n(k) = \int^1_{-1}\text{d}x \frac{(-i)^n T_n(x) e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align}
yields the results
\begin{align}
    I_1 &= i\pi \sum^n_{l = 0} (-1)^l \begin{pmatrix}
           2n+1 \\
           n-l 
         \end{pmatrix} J_{2l+1}(k),\label{eq:I_2_sol}\\
    I_2 &= 2\pi \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} + \sum^n_{l = 1} (-1)^l \begin{pmatrix}
           2n \\
           n-l 
         \end{pmatrix} J_{2l}(k) \right).
\end{align}
Question
My question now is, if there is a good way of simplifying the finite sum appearing in the result to a closed form or is there better approach to the integral in general? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Mathematica gives the results
$$I_{1,n}(k)=\int\limits_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{i k x} x^{2 n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx\\=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(-2 \left((-1)^{2 n}-1\right) \Gamma (n+1) \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(n+1;\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{k^2}{4}\right)\\+i k \left((-1)^{2 n}+1\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2},n+2;-\frac{k^2}{4}\right)\right),\quad\Re(n)>-1\tag{1}$$
and
$$I_{2,n}(k)=\int\limits_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{i k x} x^{2 n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx\\=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(2 \left((-1)^{2 n}+1\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(n+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},n+1;-\frac{k^2}{4}\right)\\-i k \left((-1)^{2 n}-1\right) \Gamma (n+1) \, _1\tilde{F}_2\left(n+1;\frac{3}{2},n+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{k^2}{4}\right)\right),\quad\Re(n)>-\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$
which are inconsistent with your derived formulas.

For example formulas (1) and (2) above evaluated at $n=1$ yield the results
$$I_{1,1}(k)=i \pi \left(\frac{3}{k} J_2(k)-J_3(k)\right)\tag{3}$$
and
$$I_{2,1}(k)=\frac{\pi}{k} J_1(k)-\pi J_2(k)\tag{4}$$
whereas your derived formulas yield the results
$$I_{1,1}(k)=i \pi (3 J_1(k)-J_3(k))\tag{5}$$
and
$$I_{2,1}(k)=-2 \pi (J_2(k)-1)\tag{6}$$
which are not equivalent.
